# How To Convert nested data to flatten data in Apache Druid

Tags: apache-nifi

{"timestamp": "1590013562019", "resource": [{"interface": {"node": {"nodeId": "145", "foreignSource": "ROUTER-Cisco_7", "foreignId": "1588700622325", "nodeLabel": "pe02.tkwl01-wa", "location": "Default"}, "instance": "default/CUST_null_null__204005419__null__ENID_AmeriGas_5-10_M_1813___74_FEDO_956790_345_PUA__FED_"}, "string": [{"name": "ifDescr", "value": "GigabitEthernet0/7/0/3.44"}, {"name": "ifSpeed", "value": "1000000000"}, {"name": "ifName", "value": "GigabitEthernet0/7/0/3.44"}, {"name": "ifHighSpeed", "value": "1000"}], "numeric": [{"group": "mib2-interfaces", "name": "ifInOctets", "value": 1047353.0, "type": "COUNTER"}, {"group": "mib2-interfaces", "name": "ifInUcastpkts", "value": 10654.0, "type": "COUNTER"}, {"group": "mib2-interfaces", "name": "ifInDiscards", "type": "COUNTER"}, {"group": "mib2-interfaces", "name": "ifInErrors", "type": "COUNTER"}, {"group": "mib2-interfaces", "name": "ifOutOctets", "value": 17206170.0, "type": "COUNTER"}, {"group": "mib2-interfaces", "name": "ifOutUcastPkts", "value": 270839.0, "type": "COUNTER"}, {"group": "mib2-interfaces", "name": "ifOutDiscards", "type": "COUNTER"}, {"group": "mib2-interfaces", "name": "ifOutErrors", "type": "COUNTER"}, {"group": "mib2-X-interfaces", "name": "ifHCInOctets", "value": 1047353.0, "type": "COUNTER"}, {"group": "mib2-X-interfaces", "name": "ifHCOutOctets", "value": 17206170.0, "type": "COUNTER"}]}, {"interface": {"node": {"nodeId": "145", "foreignSource": "ROUTER-Cisco_7", "foreignId": "1588700622325", "nodeLabel": "pe02.tkwl01-wa", "location": "Default"}, "instance": "default/CUST_null_null__204005419__null__INET_AmeriGas_5-10_M_1813___74_FEDO_956790_345_PUA__FED_"}, "string": [{"name": "ifDescr", "value": "GigabitEthernet0/7/0/3.43"}, {"name": "ifSpeed", "value": "5000000"}, {"name": "ifName", "value": "GigabitEthernet0/7/0/3.43"}, {"name": "ifHighSpeed", "value": "5"}], "numeric": [{"group": "mib2-interfaces", "name": "ifInOctets", "value": 4267618520.0, "type": "COUNTER"}, {"group": "mib2-interfaces", "name": "ifInUcastpkts", "value": 1467866477.0, "type": "COUNTER"}, {"group": "mib2-interfaces", "name": "ifInDiscards", "value": 94392.0, "type": "COUNTER"}, {"group": "mib2-interfaces", "name": "ifInErrors", "type": "COUNTER"}, {"group": "mib2-interfaces", "name": "ifOutOctets", "value": 67086932.0, "type": "COUNTER"}, {"group": "mib2-interfaces", "name": "ifOutUcastPkts", "value": 4104967945.0, "type": "COUNTER"}, {"group": "mib2-interfaces", "name": "ifOutDiscards", "value": 53719691.0, "type": "COUNTER"}, {"group": "mib2-interfaces", "name": "ifOutErrors", "type": "COUNTER"}, {"group": "mib2-X-interfaces", "name": "ifHCInOctets", "value": 429469383930.0, "type": "COUNTER"}, {"group": "mib2-X-interfaces", "name": "ifHCOutOctets", "value": 2138960804088.0, "type": "COUNTER"}]}, {"interface": {"node": {"nodeId": "145", "foreignSource": "ROUTER-Cis
-- INSERT --

Answer (score 0):

https://druid.apache.org/docs//0.15.1-incubating/ingestion/flatten-json.html
This can be used for loading particular fields into druid.

or any tools like - https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.wnameless/json-flattener/0.1.0
for flattening the events.